# How to Set an Application Page as a default landing page in SharePoint 2013 web site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to set  an Application Page(the page inside _layouts folder) as default landing page in SharePoint 2013 web application.

Is it possible to set application page as a default landing page?

If yes then How?

Answer (score 2):

To specify **directly** Application Page as a Welcome page **is not** supported, but you could create Site Page that redirects to an application page and then set Redirection page as Welcome page

### Example

For demonstration purposes let's create SharePoint Redirect page
[image]

and set `Redirect Url` property to an Application page Url (Groups page)
[image]

and finally specify `Welcome page` property to Redirect page url
[image]

Answer (score 0):

does it need to be within the layouts folder? if not place it within sharepoint like within the style library. Open up sharepoint designer and navigate to the style library -> rightclick the file and select as homepage!