# Application page as home page

Tags: development, visual-studio, application-pages, ssom

I am developing a SharePoint 2010 Project totaly in **Visual Studio and C#**.

**I do not want to use SharePoint Designer and configuration via browser.**

I need to set a **LAYOUT page (application page) as home page** on multiples sites.

Is it possible?

If not, which is the best aproach?

Important: I need to solve this situation only with c# no configuration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Set an Application Page as a default landing page in SharePoint 2013 web site](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89160/how-to-set-an-application-page-as-a-default-landing-page-in-sharepoint-2013-web)

Comment: I think is not duplicated because I need to solve with c#, not configuration.

Comment: Is it a publishing site you are working on?

Comment: No. It is not publishing site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by Arsalan Adam Khatri's answer I found a solution:

**1) First create a page to handle the redirection:**

LayoutPageRedirect.aspx

```
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=./_layouts/folder/HomePageCustom.aspx">
</head>
</html>
```

**2) Then create a module to deploy this file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="ModuleLayoutPageRedirect">
    <File Path="ModuleLayoutPageRedirect\LayoutPageRedirect.aspx" Url="LayoutPageRedirect.aspx" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

**3) Then change the welcome page**

```
SPFolder rootFolder = currentWeb.RootFolder;
string home = "LayoutPageRedirect.aspx";
rootFolder.WelcomePage = home;
rootFolder.Update();
```

**4) Finally Test**

Enter http://server/site/web

Automatically goes to:

http://server/site/web/LayoutPageRedirect.aspx

And redirected to:

http://server/site/web/_layouts/folder/HomePageCustom.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set Application pages as Welcome Page, only Site pages located either at the root web or from a Pages library.

But you can use a Redirect Page or redirection from your home page to layouts page.

Please refer to [Possible to have the default landing page of my Sharepoint Site be an applicaiton page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30419/possible-to-have-the-default-landing-page-of-my-sharepoint-site-be-an-applicaito/30420#30420)

[How to Set an Application Page as a default landing page in SharePoint 2013 web site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89160/how-to-set-an-application-page-as-a-default-landing-page-in-sharepoint-2013-web)

Comment: Thanks Arsalan. Your second link use 2013. Is it possible in 2010? And I need to do that all by code (no configuration). Can I set a redirection in c#?

Comment: Yes I think the page layout is available in 2010 as well. And yes you can use C# either embed a custom web part in a default page that redirects to your application page.

Comment: Do you have and example to set redirection using c#?

Comment: `Response.Redirect(SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/_layouts/FolderName/ApplicationPage.aspx")`

Comment: I am sorry. That's not my question. In the link you mentioned it is shown how to configure redirection on a page and then set it as your home page. All that I need to do using c # code as it applies to many sites.

Comment: Oh, so you want to programmatically create a Redirection page, and than set it as Home page?

Comment: Yes. I think it is an option based on your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can create a delegate control that would check if the current page is welcome page of the site. If Yes, then it would redirect to your application page using

C#

Response.Redirect(SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/_layouts/YourApplicationPage.aspx");

JavaScript

```
window.location.href = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_layouts/YourApplicationPage.aspx";
```

Otherwise there is no direct way of setting an application page as welcome page.

Comment: What bad news! So you're saying that there is no possibility to solve this problem without redirection?